# Not getting alert for blank task

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

I'm creating a to do list with html and JavaScript. I'm trying to create an alert for a blank task, but no alert is popping up and no errors in the console. I actually click inside of the input box, but don't type anything and leave the field blank. Then I click 'Add Task', but don't receive the alert.

HTML:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Task List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12">
                    <div id="main" class="card">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <span class="card-title">Task List</span>
                            <div class="row">
                                <for id="task-form">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input type="text" name="task" id="task">
                                        <label for="task">New Task</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Add Task" class="btn">
                                </for>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-action">
                            <h5 id="task-title">Tasks</h5>
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input type="text" name="filter" id="filter">
                                    <label for="filter">Filter Tasks</label>
                                </div>
                                <ul class="collection"></ul>
                                <a href="#" class="clear-tasks btn black">Clear Tasks</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </html>
```

JavaScript:

```
    // Define ui variables
    const form = document.querySelector('#task-form');
    const taskList = document.querySelector('.collection');
    const clearBtn = document.querySelector('.clear-tasks');
    const filter = document.querySelector('#filter');
    const taskInput = document.querySelector('#task');

    // Load all event listeners
    loadEventListeners();

    // Load all event listeners
    function loadEventListeners() {
        // Add task event
        form.addEventListener('submit', addTask);
    }

    // Add Task
    function addTask(e) {
        if(taskInput.value === ''){
            alert('Add a task');
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you mistyped `form`. It should be `<form id="task-form">` instead of `<for id="task-form">` so the proper events aren't getting called.

```js
// Define ui variables
const form = document.querySelector('#task-form');
const taskList = document.querySelector('.collection');
const clearBtn = document.querySelector('.clear-tasks');
const filter = document.querySelector('#filter');
const taskInput = document.querySelector('#task');

// Load all event listeners
loadEventListeners();

// Load all event listeners
function loadEventListeners() {
    // Add task event
    form.addEventListener('submit', addTask);
}

// Add Task
function addTask(e) {
    if(taskInput.value === ''){
        alert('Add a task');
    }

    e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Task List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <div id="main" class="card">
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <span class="card-title">Task List</span>
                        <div class="row">
                            <form id="task-form">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input type="text" name="task" id="task">
                                    <label for="task">New Task</label>
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" value="Add Task" class="btn">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <h5 id="task-title">Tasks</h5>
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <input type="text" name="filter" id="filter">
                                <label for="filter">Filter Tasks</label>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="collection"></ul>
                            <a href="#" class="clear-tasks btn black">Clear Tasks</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```